# why does the toggle not work in my file, but here in stackoverflow it does?

Tags: javascript

i am trying to embed this codepen code in my exercise file. there the toggle doesn't work. if i embed the script here in stackoverflow it works....

at which position the javascript has to be inserted, that it will work... ?

i think i already tried everything i knew...

What am I doing wrong?

thank you and best regards

```js
const toggleForm = () => {
  const container = document.querySelector('.container');
  container.classList.toggle('active');
};
```

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #f8dd30;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

section .container {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
}

section .container .user {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

section .container .user .imgBx {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ff0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

section .container .user .imgBx img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

section .container .user .formBx {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 40px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

section .container .user .formBx form h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #555;
}

section .container .user .formBx form input {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  color: #333;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin: 8px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

section .container .user .formBx form input[type='submit'] {
  max-width: 100px;
  background: #677eff;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

section .container .user .formBx form .signup {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #555;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
}

section .container .user .formBx form .signup a {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #677eff;
}

section .container .signupBx {
  pointer-events: none;
}

section .container.active .signupBx {
  pointer-events: initial;
}

section .container .signupBx .formBx {
  left: 100%;
}

section .container.active .signupBx .formBx {
  left: 0;
}

section .container .signupBx .imgBx {
  left: -100%;
}

section .container.active .signupBx .imgBx {
  left: 0%;
}

section .container .signinBx .formBx {
  left: 0%;
}

section .container.active .signinBx .formBx {
  left: 100%;
}

section .container .signinBx .imgBx {
  left: 0%;
}

section .container.active .signinBx .imgBx {
  left: -100%;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  section .container {
    max-width: 400px;
  }
  section .container .imgBx {
    display: none;
  }
  section .container .user .formBx {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Hello ondojo Zielgruppe!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bulma.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bulma-rtl.css.map">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bulma.css.map">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bulma.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bulma-rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/login.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/menu.css">
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
  <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="user signinBx">
        <div class="imgBx"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WoojinFive/CSS_Playground/master/Responsive%20Login%20and%20Registration%20Form/img1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="formBx">
          <form action="" onsubmit="return false;">
            <h2>Sign In</h2>
            <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Username" />
            <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Password" />
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Login" />
            <p class="signup">
              Don't have an account ?
              <a href="#" onclick="toggleForm();">Sign Up.</a>
            </p>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="user signupBx">
        <div class="formBx">
          <form action="" onsubmit="return false;">
            <h2>Create an account</h2>
            <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Username" />
            <input type="email" name="" placeholder="Email Address" />
            <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Create Password" />
            <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Sign Up" />
            <p class="signup">
              Already have an account ?
              <a href="#" onclick="toggleForm();">Sign in.</a>
            </p>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="imgBx"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WoojinFive/CSS_Playground/master/Responsive%20Login%20and%20Registration%20Form/img2.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? If you inspect the `.container` element, do you see the class changing? Check the Styles sidebar to see how this is affecting the CSS.

Comment: I have no errors in the console.

When iam clicking on <a href="#" onclick="toggleForm();">Sign Up.</a>

Nothing happens, like it should do in the code snippet here in the preview above...

Comment: If you add `console.log("toggling");` to the `toggleForm()` function, do you see that?

Comment: when i add the log command the console tells me "toggling"

Comment: Is it possible that you have multiple `class="container"` elements in the real site? You're toggling the first one, which may not be the one that matters.

Comment: that's it!

i had a class from bulma framework with the same class name. i renamed it to "loginBox" and now it works.

Thanks for your help!